# 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository'

Tags: perl, git

I wrote a real simple Perl script to access GitHub and set up a repo, but I'm getting `>>fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository` error.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.006;
use strict;
#use warnings

my $file;
my $dir;
my $user;
my $email;
my $repo;

print ("Enter your user name\n");
$user = <STDIN>;
chomp $user;

print ("\nEnter your email address\n");
$email = <STDIN>;
chomp $email;

print ("\nEnter a directory path..\n");
$dir = <STDIN>;
chomp ($dir);

sub openDIR{
  if (opendir(DIR, $dir)) {
    chdir $dir;
    print ("You are now in directory >>> ", $dir, "\n");
    system 'touch README';
    system 'ls -l'
  } else {
    print ("The directory can not be found, please try again");
    die;

  }
}

sub git{
  print ("Enter the name of the repo you created on Git Hub.\n");
  $repo = <STDIN>;
  chomp $repo;

  system 'git config --global user.name', $user;
  system 'git config --global user.email', $email;

  system 'git init';  
  system 'git add README';
  system "git commit -m 'first commit'";
  system "git remote add origin git\@github.com:", $user,"/", $repo, ".git";
  system  'git push origin master'
}

openDIR();
git();
```

Comment: try to stop the program after you have added the repository to see if it is actually added.

Comment: Try [Git::Wrapper](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Git::Wrapper)

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two issues here.

You have not instructed perl to do anything with the command output, nor are you testing for errors, so any error messages and return codes are being thrown away. Go read `perldoc -f system` for how to trap that. At the very least rewrite your `system` calls like this:

```
system 'git init' or die $!;
```

What's actually going wrong is this line:

```
system "git remote add origin git\@github.com:", $user,"/", $repo, ".git";
```

The comma operator does not join things together, so let me add some brackets to show you how that line looks to perl:

```
(system "git remote add origin git\@github.com:"), $user,"/", $repo, ".git";
```

This runs a not-very-useful `system` command, throws away the error, and then evaluates a load of strings in order (also not very usefully).

If you want to join strings together use the period operator. Putting it together, you probably want something like this:

```
    system "git remote add origin git\@github.com:". $user."/". $repo. ".git" or die $!;
```

You will need to fix the `git config` lines as well.

Comment: This is mostly correct, except about how the broken `system` command is parsed.  It actually means `system("git remote add origin git\@github.com:", $user,"/", $repo, ".git");` i.e. run a program named `'git remote add origin git@github.com:'` passing it 4 arguments: $user,"/", $repo, ".git".  Since you probably don't have a command named that, it fails, but you didn't check for errors.

Comment: Thanks for the advice it's been very helpful, currently reading 'perldocs' atm. however after changing to "or die $!" on my system calls Im now getting an error :"bad file descriptor"

Comment: system returns 0 on success, unlike most other things.  It also isn't useful to just check $! and not $?.  I would recommend just doing `use autodie 'system';` at the top (which internally uses IPC::System::Simple)

Comment: Strange enough after removing the "or die $!" from the system calls, the program works fine, of course also after fixing my stupid comma's. Why this is I have no idea, I would like to have some error checking,as you mentioned but It was the error checking that was giving me the new error, go figure.

Comment: Use autodie 'system' gives a compilation error: IPC::System::Simple required for Fatalised/autodying system() at GIT_script.pl line 4

Comment: As ysth said, `system` returns 0 on success, which is false, so appending `or die` means to die if the command is successful.  (Technically, `system` returns the value of `$?`, but most programs exit 0 if successful.)  The compilation error means you need to install the `IPC::System::Simple` module.  Try `cpan IPC::System::Simple`.